# How to start and stop/pause setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, setinterval

I'm trying to pause and then play a `setInterval` loop.

After I have stopped the loop, the "start" button in [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/gEdKM/) doesn't seem to work :

```js
input = document.getElementById("input");

function start() {
  add = setInterval("input.value++", 1000);
}
start();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(add)" value="stop" />
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="start" />
```

Is there a working way to do this?

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman! Using your method: http://jsfiddle.net/gEdKM/4/

Comment: Please, if you're going to use that, at least fix your timer the way that MДΓΓ БДLL's answer shows.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### The reason you're seeing this specific problem:

JSFiddle wraps your code in a function, so **`start()` is not defined in the global scope**.

[image]

---

Moral of the story: don't use inline event bindings. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)/`attachEvent`.

---

#### Other notes:

**Please** don't pass strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. It's `eval` in disguise.

Use a function instead, and get cozy with `var` and white space:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
  add;

function start() {
  add = setInterval(function() {
    input.value++;
  }, 1000);
}

start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(add)" value="stop" />
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="start" />
```

Comment: Nice. I couldn't figure out why his Fiddle wasn't behaving. Good to know. +1

Comment: yup - jsFiddle is real neat but you have to be aware of how it works differently to a plain script file.

Comment: @Web_Designer just use the code in [Alnitak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539201/139010), assuming you're actually using jQuery (as your question is tagged).

Answer (score 40):

**See Working Demo on jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qHL8Z/3/

```js
$(function() {
  var timer = null,
    interval = 1000,
    value = 0;

  $("#start").click(function() {
    if (timer !== null) return;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#input").val(++value);
    }, interval);
  });

  $("#stop").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input id="stop" type="button" value="stop" />
<input id="start" type="button" value="start" />
```

Answer (score 11):

As you've tagged this jQuery ...

First, put IDs on your input buttons and remove the inline handlers:

```
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input type="button" id="stop" value="stop"/>
<input type="button" id="start" value="start"/>
```

Then keep all of your state and functions encapsulated in a closure:

**EDIT** updated for a cleaner implementation, that also addresses @Esailija's concerns about use of `setInterval()`.

```
$(function() {
    var timer = null;
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    function tick() {
        ++input.value;
        start();        // restart the timer
    };

    function start() {  // use a one-off timer
        timer = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    };

    function stop() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    $('#start').bind("click", start); // use .on in jQuery 1.7+
    $('#stop').bind("click", stop);

    start();  // if you want it to auto-start
});
```

This ensures that none of your variables leak into global scope, and can't be modified from outside.

(Updated) working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Q6RhG/

Comment: Given that this question is tagged `jquery` (which I missed) this is the best solution.

Comment: for reference, the down votes here are because certain people disagreed with some of my views elsewhere, not because there's anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: Might want to tweak this just a tiny bit: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2aSAV/. Sorry about the lame downvotes. That's not how voting is meant to work.

Answer (score 5):

add is a local variable not a global variable try this

```js
var add;
var input = document.getElementById("input");

function start() {
  add = setInterval("input.value++", 1000);
}
start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(add)" value="stop" />
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="start" />
```

Comment: @Web_Designer - that's because of the fiddle, not because of his code. See Matt Ball's answer. Same code, but now works - http://jsfiddle.net/gEdKM/4/

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman If i could accept a comment I'd accept yours. This is the method i'll end up using.

Comment: @Web_Designer it's still using a string instead of a function in `setInterval()`

Comment: @Web_Designer - Alnitak is right. You should use Matt Ball's answer and not this one. I was just pointing out to downvoter that Jazz Man didn't deserve it.

Comment: Could you guys provide a demo to @MДΓΓ БДLL's answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Web_Designer I've updated my answer to reflect various comments and give a cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function(){
    var i = 0;
    function stop(){
        clearTimeout(i);
    }

    function start(){
        i = setTimeout( timed, 1000 );
    }

    function timed(){
       document.getElementById("input").value++;
       start();
    }

    window.stop = stop;
    window.start = start;
})()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TE3Z2/

Comment: because putting the functions into global scope and calling them from inline event handlers are _both_ poor practise.

Comment: I am down voting for the same reason Alnitak cited.

Comment: @Alnitak sure but setInterval is one of the worst practises ever. I am not downvoting people because they don't consider that. I am just working with the OP's code as close as possible, with the worst offenders removed.

Comment: @Esailija IMHO for this purpose `setInterval()` is perfectly acceptable.  The risk of timer events queueing up because they haven't been serviced is pretty negligible.

Comment: @Alnitak, right because that is the only thing bad about setInterval. sigh. How about the fact that if the elements get removed, setInterval will keep causing errors unless you do some redundant defensive code. sigh.

Comment: @Esailija what are you on about?  A repeating `setTimeout()` loop would have exactly the same _hypothetical_ problem.

Comment: @Alnitak No it wouldn't, it would cause one error and then stop.

Comment: @Esailija you're picking nits in a hypothetical situation that this code doesn't have.  EOD.

Answer (score 0):

I use multiple timers this way. It isn't an elegant solution but it works well.

```
var timerclass = function () {
    this.initialTime = Date.now();
    var t=this;
    var Timer = setInterval(function(){t.checkTime();}, 1000); //start the timer (goes to function checkTime every 1000ms )
    this.timerstart=false;      
}; //end of constructor

timerclass.prototype.StartTheTimer = function(){    
    this.initialTime = Date.now(); //Time right now
    this.timerstart=true;
};      
    
timerclass.prototype.checkTime= function(){ 
    if(this.timerstart==true)
    {
        var timeDifference = Date.now() - this.initialTime; 
        console.log("Time ms: "+timeDifference);        
   }
};  
    
timerclass.prototype.StopTimer= function(){
    this.timerstart=false;
};      
    
module.exports = timerclass;
```

Then in your main code:

```
var MyTimerSystem = require(__dirname+'/class.timerclass.js');
var MyFirstTimerObject = new MyTimerSystem(); //First Timer 
var MySecondTimerObject = new MyTimerSystem(); //Second Timer
```

Stop the timer(s):

```
MyFirstTimerObject.StopTimer(); //Stop First Timer
MySecondTimerObject.StopTimer(); //Stop Second Timer
```

Restart the timer(s) from 0ms again:

```
MyFirstTimerObject.StartTheTimer();  //Start or restart the First timer
MySecondTimerObject.StartTheTimer(); //Start or restart the Second timer
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="button" onclick="mySetIntervalOff()" value="stop" />
  <input type="button" onclick="startInicio()" value="start" />

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var mySetInterval;

    function startInicio() {
      mySetInterval = setInterval(function() {
        const date = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      }, 1000);
    }
    startInicio();
    clearInterval(mySetInterval);

    function mySetIntervalOff() {
      clearInterval(mySetInterval);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can't stop a timer function mid-execution. You can only catch it after it completes and prevent it from triggering again.